# How do I change the style of a single button inside a *ngFor in Ionic 3?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I am trying to change the style of the specific button I click in the *ngFor in the ion-col. Currently when I click on a button, the styles for all buttons changes at the same time.

Here are my codes:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of displayRestaurant[0].seatTimeSlotAndDiscount | slice:indexStart:indexEnd; let i=index" no-padding>
  <button ion-button style="border-radius:100px;height:70px;width:70px;text-align:center;" (click)="clickedDiscount(item)"  [ngClass]="clickedDiscountBoolean ? 'discountClicked' : 'discountUnclicked'">
    <p style="font-size: 10px; color:white;">{{item.percentageDiscount}}</p>
    <p style="font-size:10px;color:white;">{{item.timeOfDiscount}}</p>
  </button>
</ion-col>
```

SCSS:

```
.discountClicked{
    border: 3px solid orange;
}

.discountUnclicked{
    border:none;
}
```

.ts:

```
clickedDiscount(discount:Discount){
  this.clickedDiscountBoolean = !this.clickedDiscountBoolean;
}
```

Originally it is like this:
[image]

Here is what my current codes do after I clicked on any of the buttons (The new style is applied to all):
[image]

What I am looking for is, when I click on any of the buttons, only that button's style will change, and the rest will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your buttons look up for same condition. You need to unify that condition to be true for only one button. You can use index value for that :

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of displayRestaurant[0].seatTimeSlotAndDiscount | slice:indexStart:indexEnd; let i=index" no-padding>
  <button ion-button style="border-radius:100px;height:70px;width:70px;text-align:center;" 
      (click)="clickedDiscount(item,i)"  
      [ngClass]="clickedIndex ===  i ? 'discountClicked' : 'discountUnclicked'">
    <p style="font-size: 10px; color:white;">{{item.percentageDiscount}}</p>
    <p style="font-size:10px;color:white;">{{item.timeOfDiscount}}</p>
  </button>
</ion-col>
```

Then in your component

```
clickedDiscount(discount:Discount,index:number){
  this.clickedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: I have amended the codes but now upon loading the app, all the buttons have the border around them before I click on any of them.

Comment: @BryanArtic sorry i removed your borderless class from the template. Re-added it.

Comment: It's alright, but it didn't affect the outcome though. All buttons still have a border around them before I click on any of them.

Comment: @BryanArtic there was a typo with `index` can you try again.

Comment: I have modified the codes. Now when I load, the buttons are all preset (no border). But after I clicked any of them, the styling didn't change. :(

Comment: @BryanArtic i hate to find another typo when i recheck my code.