# How to apply active class to anchor links in a horizontal menu in SCSS

Tags: html, angular, sass

I'm trying to achieve toggle functionality between several anchor links in a horizontal menu. The problem I'm facing currently is, the `active` class is not being applied to links.

What I was expecting is, when user clicks on the link, the color of the text should change. Only the selected link text color should change.

**SCSS**

```
.link-active{
    &:active,
    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
    <span *ngFor="let menuOption of homePageMenu; let i = index;">
        <a class="menu-chip"
        [ngClass]="{'link-active': isActive}"
        (click)="handleMenuItemClick(i)">{{menuOption.name}}</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I created a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/anchor-menu-toggle) using StackBlitz. Could anyone please guide.

Comment: If you set `isActive` true it will be true for all the `a` elements. So you need to unify that condition like this : `[ngClass]="{'link-active': selectedIndex === i}"` and for click = ` (click)="selectedIndex = i"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the style of a single button inside a \*ngFor in Ionic 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333638/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-a-single-button-inside-a-ngfor-in-ionic-3)

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't. I am working with link states but not with buttons @Eldar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code in StackBlitz. check it out
https://stackblitz.com/edit/anchor-menu-toggle-9vfa8i

**Edited**

I have change the followings

1. in the ts file 
   `isActive = false;` to `activeIndex = false;` to get the current activated index
2. In the toggle function change to get the clicked index and assign to the `activeIndex`
3. in SCSS
    
   `&:active` to `&.active` , I used  `active` as a class, not pseudo state
4. In the html `[class.active]="activeIndex==i"` added because when `activeIndex` equels to loop index the `active` class will add to the element

I hope this will clear every thing.

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted! Could you also please edit your answer with what you did.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use a `[routerLinkActive]="your-active-class"` directive in an anchor tag and it will automatically toggle the classes for you.